# ArgumentException: GetComponent requires that the requested component 'GameObject' derives from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an interface

Tags: unity-game-engine

I tried to make a system so that it would analyse  all of the children of a given parent and based on one of the children whom is active, decide upon what the forward and right of that child is:

```
        Vector3 camF = new Vector3(0,0,0);
        Vector3 camR = new Vector3(0,0,0);
        //Assign active camera to current cam.
        GameObject[] cameras = GetComponentsInChildren<GameObject>();
        foreach (GameObject currentCam in cameras)
        {
            if (currentCam.activeInHierarchy)
            {
                camF = currentCam.transform.forward;
                camR = currentCam.transform.right;
            }
        }
```

While the game does boot, I cannot move my character, and keep on getting this error message:

```
ArgumentException: GetComponent requires that the requested component 'GameObject' derives from MonoBehaviour or Component or is an interface.
UnityEngine.GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren[T] (System.Boolean includeInactive) (at <58a34b0a618d424bb5fc18bb9bcdac20>:0)
UnityEngine.Component.GetComponentsInChildren[T] (System.Boolean includeInactive) (at <58a34b0a618d424bb5fc18bb9bcdac20>:0)
UnityEngine.Component.GetComponentsInChildren[T] () (at <58a34b0a618d424bb5fc18bb9bcdac20>:0)
PerspectiveControls.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Character/PerspectiveControls.cs:32)
```

Comment: Try something like:
GameObject[] cameras = GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>().Skip(1).Select(_ => _.gameObject).ToArray();

Comment: It says that Transform doesn't contain a definition for skip

Comment: Then you probably typed GetComponentInChildren instead of GetComponentsInChildren

Comment: you need to add using System.Linq;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're using `GetComponent` method but `GameObject` is not a component. On the other hand, transform contains all the children. So, in order to get children Transforms, you can use this:

```
foreach (Transform child in transform)
```

And in order to reach the GameObject, you can do this:

```
child.gameObject
```